# "object not found" error while creating a multisite

Tags: multi-sites

i have an existing working D7 site in my local. when i tried to create another site with same code-base and different db, it is showing "object not found" on hitting url. Below are the list of steps i followed:

**Created testdb with testuser.**

**Created directory named as "*domain2*" for multisite inside xampp/htdocs/drupal/sites**

Copied default.settings.php from existing site to "domain2/sites/default" folder and added testdb details.Given write permissions.

**host file:**
127.0.0.1   domain2

**http-vhost.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal7"
                     ServerName domain2
                  </VirtualHost>
```

When i hit localhost/domain2, it is showing "Object not found" error in browser.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Is the new database empty? I think you should start the normal D7 installation with the second site without manually adding the connection details in the `settings.php` file.
Also, the file should be name `settings.php` not `default.settings.php`

Comment: db is empty. the file name is settings.php. still it is showing the same error.

Comment: You should delete the settings.php file and start a normal install